# How to group related MySQL records in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, relational

I have a problem with a SQL query in PHP. I've tried everything but it doesn't want to play ball. The output is as follows:

```
Pat48
48
47
47
46
46
Jana47
Luc46
```

I need it to be in groups eg.

```
Pat48
48
48
Jana47
47
47
Luc46 
46
46
```

The code is as follows:

```
<?php
//Let's connect
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("the database");
$get_albums = "SELECT album_id, album_title FROM albums ORDER BY album_id    DESC";
$get_pictures = "SELECT picture_id, picture_title, picture_link, album FROM pictures WHERE album=album ORDER BY picture_id DESC LIMIT 1, 18446744073709551615";
$albums = mysql_query($album);
$first_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($first);
$picture_result = mysql_query($get_pictures);

$album_result = mysql_query($get_albums);
while($first_row = mysql_fetch_array($album_result))
{
    echo "<p>{$first_row['album_title']}{$first_row['album_id']}
    </p>";
    {
        while(list($picture_id, $picture_title, $picture_link, $album) =     mysql_fetch_row($picture_result))
        {
        echo "<p>{$album}</p>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This seems to work thanks to you guys

```
$get_albums = "SELECT album_id, album_title FROM albums ORDER BY album_id DESC";
$album_result = mysql_query($get_albums);

while($first_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($album_result))
{
    echo "<p>{$first_row['album_title']}</p>";

    $get_pictures = "SELECT picture_id, picture_title, picture_link, album FROM pictures WHERE album={$first_row['album_id']} ORDER BY album DESC LIMIT 1, 18446744073709551615";
    $picture_result = mysql_query($get_pictures);

    while($picture_row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($picture_result))
    {
        echo "<p>{$picture_row['picture_title']}</p>";
    }
}
```

Now I have the following problem.

I'm trying to combine this with colorbox but now when I click on a link it outputs all the same 4 first pages in each slide show. Code is as followed.

```
$get_albums = "SELECT album_id, album_title FROM albums ORDER BY album_id DESC";
$album_result = mysql_query($get_albums);

while($first_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($album_result))
{
    $first = mysql_query("SELECT picture_id, picture_title, picture_link, album FROM pictures WHERE album={$first_row['album_id']} ORDER BY album DESC LIMIT 1");
    $first_picture = mysql_fetch_assoc($first);

    echo "<p><a class='group1' title=\"{$first_picture['picture_title']}\"   href={$first_picture['picture_link']}>{$first_row['album_title']}</a></p>";

    $get_pictures = "SELECT picture_id, picture_title, picture_link, album FROM pictures WHERE album={$first_row['album_id']} ORDER BY album DESC LIMIT 1, 18446744073709551615";
    $picture_result = mysql_query($get_pictures);

    while($picture_row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($picture_result))
    {
        echo "<p><a class='group1' title=\"{$picture_result['picture_title']}\"     href={$picture_result['picture_link']}>{$first_row['album_title']}</a></p>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: *"I need it to be in groups"* => [**GROUP BY**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: You could also do the grouping manually, by detecting changes in `album_id`.

Comment: It's giving me a right headache, been trying for 2 days now

Answer (score 0):

The query for the pictures should be inside the loop of each album,
mysql does not automatically join the two queries, you need to pass the album id to the second query using the php value returned from the first query but inside the loop where you loop the albums.

Something like this:

```
<?php
//Let's connect
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("the database");
$get_albums = "SELECT album_id, album_title FROM albums ORDER BY album_id    DESC";
$album_result = mysql_query($get_albums);

while($first_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($album_result)){
    echo "<p>{$first_row['album_title']}{$first_row['album_id']}</p>";

    $get_pictures = "SELECT picture_id, picture_title, picture_link, album FROM pictures WHERE album_id={$first_row['album_id']} ORDER BY picture_id DESC";
    $picture_result = mysql_query($get_pictures);

    while(list($picture_id, $picture_title, $picture_link, $album) =     mysql_fetch_row($picture_result)){
        echo "<p>{$picture_id}</p>";
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: No Joy, Now it just outputs the albums

Comment: This seems to work$get_albums = "SELECT album_id, album_title FROM albums ORDER BY album_id DESC";
$album_result = mysql_query($get_albums);

while($first_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($album_result))
{
echo "<p>{$first_row['album_title']}</p>";

$get_pictures = "SELECT picture_id, picture_title, picture_link, album FROM pictures WHERE album={$first_row['album_id']} ORDER BY album DESC LIMIT 1, 18446744073709551615";
$picture_result = mysql_query($get_pictures);

while($picture_row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($picture_result))
{
echo "<p>{$picture_row['picture_title']}</p>";
}
}